# Control my hair cards with bones

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, hair

I'm trying to make animals with feathers, hair and other features for videogames, I'm using hair cards to put the hair, but the hair of these animals must be able to stand up, or straighten, so that they help me express emotions.

regardless of the complexity involved in putting card by card, I want to put a bone on each card, to manipulate it, but the problem is that these bones follow their father in a very rigid way, while the base mesh deforms, the difference between the bones of the cards, and the base mesh ends up becoming evident and unpleasant.

Is there a way to make these bones in my cards "warp with the mesh", instead of just following their parent bone?

Comment: Could the Wiggle Bone add-on help with this?

Comment: Is there any tutorial on this add-on?